# Raspberry Pi Zero & TP-Link TL-WN725N v1

Tags: wifi, pi-zero

I'm trying to hook up my Wi-Fi adapter(TP-Link TL-WN725N v1) to my Raspberry Pi Zero.

Even though I'm able to find [some drivers](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982#p462982) for the adapter for some of the Raspberry revisions(model 3, 2B), I don't see anything listed for the Zero or anything for the kernel version `4.14.79+`.

Has anyone ever made this Wi-Fi adapter work with the Zero?

Comment: so, the `*.4.14.79-1159.tar.gz` files, like `8188eu-4.14.79-1159.tar.gz` don't work? - oh, wait, what you linked to was drivers for *TP-Link TL-WN725N **v2*** ...

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, that’s straw one and the other is that there is no mention of rPi Zero anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've handled it by following the instructions in [here](http://raspberry-at-home.com/wifi-configuration/).

It turns out that Raspbian Stretch comes with the necessary firmware. So it was just about entering in my Wi-Fi credentials.

Comment: For posterity, you could have saved yourself some hassle by checking `ip link` for the interface.  On a stock Pi Zero, you would normally just have one listing, loopback (`lo`). If there is an additional one and you have a wifi adapter plugged in, that's what it will be (probably `wlan0`), indicating there is a driver in place already.  *Beware the the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)!*

Comment: @goldilocks While you're technically correct, there are just two microUSB inputs on an rPi Zero; one is for USB while the other for power. Since I had to do some configurations first(hence requiring internet), I'd to route my notebook's internet to my rPi Zero via USB. Therefore I couldn't insert my Wi-Fi dongle at the same time since I don't have the proper hub.